# Generate smooth directional/tangent vector field using guide vectors on random points

Tags: vector, field

[image]

1. Blue dots are randomly generated points in UV space. (0-1)
2. Red arrows represent guide vectors. (position and direction)
3. An algorithm that can generate direction on points based on guide vectors (right image)

I gave a try using the K-Nearest-Neighbor algorithm but the resulting vectors are not following guide vectors smoothly. This [paper](https://hhoppe.com/proj/vfdesign/) and [video](https://hhoppe.com/vfdesign_planck_bricks.wmv) is describing the solution but unfortunately, there is no source code.